# How to manage a priced app; in terms of timing and managing after license expiry?

Tags: user-expectation, time, features, selling-ux, pricing

I am developing a desktop app; and it is the first time I intend to publish it to the public for selling.

I have two options for pricing, and two options for managing after license expiry.

**The two options for pricing are:**

1. Setting a limited time period by setting an expiration date. The
   app license must expire when reaching the expiration date regardless of whether the app was used or not.
2. Setting a counter to accumulate the usage hours. The app will
   only expire after consuming the number of predetermined usage
   hours. Counting consumed usage hours is only performed when the app is running.

**The two options for managing after license expiry are:**

1. Blocking the whole app after license expiry and only presenting the
   user with a registration dialogue for buying a new license.
2. Blocking some features after license expiry and notifying the user
   of that; and provide them with an option for buying a new license to     obtain full functionality.

*Which is considered better in terms of user experience and user expectations, so that it doesn't leave a bad experience or impression?*

If you have other options/suggestions; you are welcome ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I would go for **First Option** of the pricing options simply because

**Cons of second option**

- I don't want the user to keep worrying about that ticking timer on his face. Most likely user will end up getting distracted.
- If you give the user 48 hours of app usage, user might be able to manage his usage of the app in such a way that his licensce won't expire for Weeks or Months.
- More often than not you will use his local desktop time to count usage hours, and his desktop time can be manipulated by the user.

**Pros of first option**

- It is more widely used and simple to get used to.
- It is easier to count and difficult to manipulate, resulting in lesser confusion/conflict with user.

As far as **managing after license expiry** is concerned, I think it is more of a CEO's decision rather than UX decision, since it related to your business goals and your buyer's (if this is B2B) business goals. I can only suggest that **second one** is more common and expected by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question about an expired license, I would only block some features. The user already bought your license before and it would be a nice gesture to still offer them some features. Of course with the option to still buy a new license like you already mentioned.